# Receive root level and nested Items from List using Lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a class like this:

```
public class Item
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private bool isAction1Possible;
    public bool IsAction1Possible
    {
        get { return isAction1Possible; }
        set { isAction1Possible = value; }
    }

    private bool isAction2Possible;
    public bool IsAction2Possible
    {
        get { return isAction2Possible; }
        set { isAction2Possible = value; }
    }

    private bool isAction1Selected;
    public bool IsAction1Selected
    {
        get { return isAction1Selected; }
        set 
        { 
            if(IsAction2Selected)
                IsAction2Selected = false;
            isAction1Selected = value; 
        }
    }

    private bool isAction2Selected;
    public bool IsAction2Selected
    {
        get { return isAction2Selected; }
        set 
        { 
            if(IsAction1Selected)
                IsAction1Selected = false;
            isAction2Selected = value; 
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<int, Item> dependencies = new Dictionary<int, Item>();
    public Dictionary<int, Item> Dependencies
    {
        get { return dependencies; }
        set { dependencies = value; }
    }
}
```

The `Dependencies` `Dictionary` carries instances of the `Items` class.
I now have a `List` where I've added all `Items` where either `IsAction1Possible` or `IsAction2Possible` is `true` which is being presented to the user. The user now selects items which he wants to have further processed which will set the `IsActionXSelected` property to `true`.

Finally I wanted to use a Lambda query to receive all of the "Base" Items in that `List` where `IsAction1Possible` is `true` and `IsAction1Selected` is `true` **and** all `Items` in the `Dependencies` `Dictionary` where `IsAction1Possible` is `true`.

I was able to receive either all of the Base items using `Select` or all of the Dependency items using `SelectMany`.

This is what I tried but I ended up with only the base items and not the dependencies. Is it even possible to do it in one query I will I have to do one for the Base items and one for the Dependencies? Thanks for any hints!

```
IEnumerable<Item> toBeProcessed = ItemsAction1Enabled
                .Where(i => i.IsAction1Possible == true && i.IsAction1Selected == true).ToList()
                .SelectMany(d => d.Dependencies.Values)
                .Where(d => d.Action1Possible == true);
```